# How to set content by referring to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to set content to each button.

I have array and would like to set `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`.

But now,in my work below, the result is a little different.

Are there any way to achieve it ?

Thanks

```js
arr=["A","B","C","D"]

$(".button").text(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean the four buttons get the four values from the array? Button 1  text 'A', button 2 'B' ...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.button` will give a all the elements with same class , you need to iterate it. Use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate the object. `each` takes first argument as the element and second one as `index`. Use this `index` to retrieve the value from array. Then use [text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the content of the button

```js
let arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

$(".button").each(function(i, v) {
  $(v).text(arr[i])

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
  <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer of brk is completly valid I'd personally create a unique button for each element inside your array. This way you dont run into problems if there is not enough buttons in your html for each element or vice versa.

```js
arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


arr.forEach(element => createButton(element));

function createButton(text) {
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  newButton.setAttribute('class', 'button');
  newButton.innerHTML = text;
  document.body.appendChild(newButton);
}
```

Comment: Or, as OP is using jquery already: `arr.forEach(txt => $("body").append(\`<button class='button'>${txt}\`));`

Comment: Very nice one-liner! Thanks! @freedomn-m